# Binding Repeater data to Dynamic tab in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to bind the repeater's data to Dynamic tab of year the image for which i am attaching
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyrjB.png)
the repeater code is as below:

```
                <!--begin isotope -->
                <div class="isotope col-lg-12">


                    <!--begin portfolio filter -->
                    <ul id="filter" class="option-set clearfix">                            
                        <li data-filter="*" class="selected"><a>All</a></li>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rpYear" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpYear_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li data-filter='<%#Eval("Year") %>'>
                                    <a>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Year") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>


                    <ul id="list" class="portfolio_list clearfix">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rpImagedetails" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 <%#Eval("Year") %> ">
                                    <div class="recent-item">
                                        <figure>
                                            <div class="touching medium">
                                                <img src='<%# "FileUpload/Eventpic/"+ Eval("Image") %>' alt="" />
                                                <div class="hovers">
                                                    <a href='<%# "FileUpload/Eventpic/"+ Eval("Image") %>' class="hover-zoom mfp-image" style="left: 45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                    <!--<a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <figcaption class="item-description">
                                                <h5><%#Eval("Title") %></h5>
                                                <span><%#Eval("Date") %>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <%#Eval("Stallno") %>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <%#Eval("Location") %></span>
                                            </figcaption>
                                        </figure>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!--./span12-->
        </div>
```

**the code behind file is as below:**

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetYear();
        BindEventVideo1();
    }

```
public void GetYear()
{

    DataSet ds = EventVideo.GetYear();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rpYear.DataSource = ds;
        rpYear.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void rpYear_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Repeater rpImages = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rpImagedetails");
        Label item = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl");
        string Year = item.Text;
        ViewState["Year"] = Year;
    }
}
public void BindEventVideo1()
{

    DataSet ds = EventVideo.GetyearImages(ViewState["Year"].ToString());
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rpImagedetails.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        rpImagedetails.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I am new to asp.net  so kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

**the Html code is**

```
<div class="isotope col-lg-12">

                        <!--begin portfolio filter -->
                            <ul id="filter" class="option-set clearfix">
                            <li data-filter="*" class="selected"><a href="#">All</a></li>
                            <li data-filter=".2014"><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                            <li data-filter=".2012"><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                           <!-- <li data-filter=".2011"><a href="#">2011</a></li>-->
                            <li data-filter=".2010"><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!--end portfolio filter -->

                        <!--begin portfolio_list -->
                        <ul id="list" class="portfolio_list clearfix">
                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->

                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2014">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2014-1.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2014-1.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image"  style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <!--<a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2014</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 8th - 12th Jan '2014. <br>
     Stall No: H2A55
<br>
     BIEC,
     Bangalore, India</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->
 <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->

                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2014">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2014-2.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2014-2.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image"  style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <!--<a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2014</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 8th - 12th Jan '2014. <br>
     Stall No: H2A55
<br>
     BIEC,
     Bangalore, India</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->

                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <!--<li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2012">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio/portfolio_2.png" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="img/portfolio/full/portfolio_2.png" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Power & Electricity World Africa 2012</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 27th - 28th March '2012<br>
Stall No: ZNB-9 IND 10,

Sandton Convention Centre,
Johannesburg, South Africa</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>-->
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->

                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2012">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2012-1.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2012-1.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image"  style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <!--<a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2012</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 18th - 22nd Jan'2012<br>
Stall No: H5 E10R70<br>

Bombay Exhibition Centre,
Mumbai, INDIA</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->
                             <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2012">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2012-2.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2012-2.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image"  style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <!--<a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2012</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 18th - 22nd Jan'2012<br>
Stall No: H5 E10R70<br>

Bombay Exhibition Centre,
Mumbai, INDIA</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->
                             <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2012">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2012-3.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2012-3.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image"  style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <!--<a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2012</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 18th - 22nd Jan'2012<br>
Stall No: H5 E10R70<br>

Bombay Exhibition Centre,
Mumbai, INDIA</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->



                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <!--<li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2012">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio/portfolio_4.png" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="img/portfolio/full/portfolio_4.png" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Middle East Electricity 2012</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 7th - 9th Feb'2012<br>
     Stall No: ZN 18
     India Pavalion <br>

     International Exhibition Centre,
     Dubai, UAE</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>-->
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->

                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <!--<li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2011">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio/portfolio_5.png" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="img/portfolio/full/portfolio_5.png" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Middle East Electricity 2011</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 8th - 10th Feb'2011<br>
     Stall No: ZQ 58, 
     India Pavalion <br>

     International Exhibition Centre,
     Dubai, UAE</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>-->
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->

                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2010">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2010-1.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2010-1.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image"  style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <!--<a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2010</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 20th - 24th Jan'2010<br>
Stall No: H1 G50<br>

Bombay Exhibition Centre,
Mumbai, INDIA</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->
                             <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2010">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2010-2.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2010-2.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                               <!-- <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link alone"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2010</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 20th - 24th Jan'2010<br>
Stall No: H1 G50<br>

Bombay Exhibition Centre,
Mumbai, INDIA</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->
                             <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 2010">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="images/events/2010-3.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="images/events/full/2010-3.jpg" class="hover-zoom mfp-image"  style="left:45%;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                               <!-- <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>Elecrama 2010</h5>
                                            <span>Date : 20th - 24th Jan'2010<br>
Stall No: H1 G50<br>

Bombay Exhibition Centre,
Mumbai, INDIA</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->



                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <!--<li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 responsive">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio/portfolio_7.png" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="img/portfolio/full/portfolio_7.png" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>consectetur adipisicing</h5>
                                            <span>Technology</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>-->

                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->

                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <!--<li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 branding">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio/portfolio_8.png" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="img/portfolio/full/portfolio_8.png" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>ipsum dolor</h5>
                                            <span>Technology</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>-->
                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->

                            <!-- Begin Portfolio item -->
                            <!--<li class="list_item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 branding">
                                <div class="recent-item">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="touching medium">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio/portfolio_9.png" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hovers">
                                                <a href="img/portfolio/full/portfolio_2.png" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                <a href="portfolio_single.html" class="hover-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <figcaption class="item-description">
                                            <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
                                            <span>Technology</span>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </li>-->

                            <!-- End Portfolio item -->
                        </ul> <!--end portfolio_list -->
                    </div>
```

**Adding the Image from view code**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGvwV.png)

Comment: Your code seems correct. What happen when you run that?

Comment: @Piyush Khatri . when i run the code the images are populated according to the last and latest year .in the image the latest year was 2012 ,so it shows only that pics and data ,ignoring the 2010 data and also since <li> of all is outside the repeater only that shows the output. when i click on the respected year tab like when i click on 2012 tab..Images vanish.

Comment: Also i feel it is due to Filter-item property. as in html file it usses class property to fetch the images and data and here i have replaced it with eval and i am not able to fetch data due to it

Comment: Do you have html of your code? Please share it here. Because we need to construct repeater according to html so that your filter works.

Comment: @Piyush Khatri i have uploaded the html section in main question

Comment: It seems correct to me, can you check view source of it. What happen in html when repeater renders it?

Comment: @Piyush Khatri .i have shared the view source of it and there too it tends to get the eval value

Comment: View source, I mean what you generated when you run page.

Comment: There also it seems to generate the eval but unable to fetch when i click the tabs  
@Piyush Khatri

Comment: I see that you used label within anchor tag, it means it generates span. I think that causes an issue. Please try to maintain same structure as it html requires for tabbing, then only it will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 repeater if you are using ASP.NET(aspx and ascx)
1) for displaying year as a tab
2) another repeater for displaying images with details

Step-to-follow
1) Have this all data in dataset set in session
2) get distinct year and add default tab as 'All' and bind this year data to Repeater as horizontal, each repeater cell contains the link button and on click you have to redirect to server and get the filtered records from the session dataset and show it on 2nd repeater

2)on each 1st repeater-link button click event- get the year and filter out the records from session database and create in-memory dataset and fill it and bind it to 2nd dataset

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the reason for it.

```
 <ul id="filter" class="option-set clearfix">
                            <li data-filter="*" class="selected"><a>All</a></li>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rpYear" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>           

                                     <li data-filter=".<%#Eval("Year") %>"><a href="#"><%#Eval("Year") %></a></li>

                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </ul>
```

In earlier Question i was missing anchor tag section ,so it was not able to target to repeater and also In this  <%#Eval("Year") %>  i missed out DOT(.) representing the class.